# Use dynamic templates with data passed through the send email API in SendGrid

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

everyone.

We are new to the SendGrid API world. We are building a web application that will send emails to customers based on the status of transactions, and we would like to use dynamic templates to provide some marketing material, such as background pictures, etc.

The question.  What do we need to do on the Dynamic template side that will tell SendGrid to use the data that is being passed through the API on top of the created dynamic template?  Is this possible to do?

Comment: Maybe this [docs page](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-templates) can help you getting started. Please note that this is a developer-focused forum and good questions come with code and a minimal viable example to reproduce a concrete issue. It's unfortunately not the right place for general questions.